# Optimalization of select containing Union

Tags: sql, oracle, union, query-performance

I have and easy select:

```
define account_id = 7
select * from A where ACCOUNT_ID = &account_id
UNION
select * from B where ACCOUNT_ID = &account_id;
```

I would like to have account_id as input from another select and I did it this way:

```
select * from A where ACCOUNT_ID in(select accound_id from ACCOUNTS where EMAIL like 'aa@aa.com') -- id 7 returned
UNION
select * from B where ACCOUNT_ID in(select accound_id from ACCOUNTS where EMAIL like 'aa@aa.com')
```

How could be this optimalized to call `select accound_id from ACCOUNTS where EMAIL like 'aa@aa.com'` only once?

Comment: Step 1: Can you do  `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`?

Comment: `select accound_id from ACCOUNTS where EMAIL like 'aa@aa.com` assign the result of this query to a variable and use that variable in union

Comment: Rewrite the query using where exists instead of using In statement

Comment: I'd `UNION [ALL]` first, and then the join the result with the current subquery.

Comment: But the main question is, why do you have two such similar tables A and B? Can't you have one common table instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first question is whether the `union` can be replaced by the `union all`.  So, my first attempt would be to use `exists` and `union all`:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1
              from accounts aa
              where aa.account_id = a.account_id and
                    aa.email = 'aa@aa.com'
             )
union all
select b.*
from b
where exists (select 1
              from accounts aa
              where aa.account_id = b.account_id and
                    aa.email = 'aa@aa.com'
             );
```

For this structure, you want an index on `accounts(account_id, email)`.  The `exists` simply looks up the values in the index.  This does require scanning `a` and `b`.

If the query is returning a handful of rows and you want to remove duplicates, then `union` and replace `union all`.  If it is returning a large set of rows -- and there are not duplicates in each table and there is an easy way to identify the duplicates -- then you can instead do:

```
with cte_a as (
      select a.*
      from a
      where exists (select 1
                    from accounts aa
                    where aa.account_id = a.account_id and
                          aa.email = 'aa@aa.com'
                   )
       )
select cte_a.*
from ctea_a
union all
select b.*
from b
where exists (select 1
              from accounts aa
              where aa.account_id = b.account_id and
                    aa.email = 'aa@aa.com'
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from cte_a
                  where cte_a.? = b.?  -- whatever is needed to identify duplicates
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where `WITH` comes in handy

```
WITH ids AS (select account_id from ACCOUNTS where EMAIL like 'aa@aa.com')
select * from A where ACCOUNT_ID in ids
UNION ALL
select * from B where ACCOUNT_ID in ids;
```

I also changed it to `UNION ALL`, because it's much faster.